# Change unix user environment

Tags: linux

Logged in as `user1`, I'd like to project to another unix user env, let's say `user2`, without type it's password.

By "project", I mean:
- change current `$HOME`
- call `user2`'s bash startup scripts (to get it's prompt and global vars)

What I've written a little script `switch_user_env.sh`:

```
HOME="/usr/users/$1"
cd "$HOME"

bash

. /etc/profile

if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_profile" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bash_profile"
fi

if [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.profile"
fi
```

I call it like following: `. ./switch_user_env.sh user2`

Current shell get correctly change to bash but startup scripts are not called.

Can you help me to understand what is wrong ?

Thanks !

[EDIT]
`switch_user_env.sh` source code is available in GitHub: https://github.com/pierrefevrier/switch-user-env

Comment: You've started a new shell with the call to bash. It reads its own startup files. If you type exit, your current shell will continue with your script. Look into the `su` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because remaining part your script (after **bash** call) will be executed after you exit from bash (type exit command or "Ctrl+d"). Calling bash in your script takes the control of futher execution.

Here is updated version:

```
HOME="/usr/users/$1"
cd "$HOME"

SOURCE_PROFILE=/etc/profile

if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_profile" ]; then
    SOURCE_PROFILE="$HOME/.bash_profile"
fi

if [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ]; then
    SOURCE_PROFILE="$HOME/.profile"
fi


bash --rcfile "$SOURCE_PROFILE"
```

Comment: So how can I call commands after bash one, to be executed in the new current bash ?

Comment: Please refer to updated post

Comment: Thanks that's clear. But why `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` are not called automatically when calling `bash` command ?

Comment: They are called. But ~/.bash_profile of currently logged in user. But you want to load environment of the different user. Other than currently logged in. Please refer to bash man page also for more details.

Comment: Ok, I thought bash refers to current `$HOME` to call startup scripts not thoses of current logged in user. Thanks for your explainations !